# CD burning....Debug works,Published doesnt

Tags: c#, xbap

I am working on a program to burn a CD.  Its located on a server but to my knowledge when it is ran it is pulled to that users computer, then ran.

My problem is it runs in debug and after I publish it to the server, it can no longer find my CD burner.

I can provide more information, i just don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\Windows Presentation Foundation\Hosting node in the registry and create a new DWORD named RunUnrestricted with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is a Win Forms or a WPF application then it will work with resources on the local machine (machine it was launched on). If you want to burn CDs remotely you will need another tier located on the server - probably come kind of service.

Comment: its wpf but the problem is that it does not recognize my CD burner unless im in debug